# A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC Web API applications with latest MVC framework, C#, .NET Framework 4.5.1 and Ninject (latest version). I'm developing it on Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, IIS Express and Windows 8.1 64 bits.

I'm getting this error:

Error when trying to create a controller of type `UsersController`. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

When I do `http://mymachine:11156/api/users`.

This is my `NinjectConfigurator` class.

```
public class NinjectConfigurator
{
    public void Configure(IKernel container)
    {
        AddBindings(container);

        var resolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(container);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }

    private void AddBindings(IKernel container)
    {
        ConfigureLog4net(container);

        // Unit of work.
        container.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<EFDbContext>().InRequestScope();

        // Repositories.
        container.Bind<IGenericRepository<User>>().To<GenericRepository<User>>();
        container.Bind<IGenericRepository<Group>>().To<GenericRepository<Group>>();
        container.Bind<IGenericRepository<Message>>().To<GenericRepository<Message>>();

        // Fetchers.
        container.Bind<IHttpUserFetcher>().To<HttpUserFetcher>();

        // Mappers.
        container.Bind<IGroupMapper>().To<GroupMapper>();
        container.Bind<IMessageMapper>().To<MessageMapper>();
        container.Bind<IUserMapper>().To<UserMapper>();
    }

    private void ConfigureLog4net(IKernel container)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        var loggerForWebSite = LogManager.GetLogger("MattSocialNetworkWebApi");
        container.Bind<ILog>().ToConstant(loggerForWebSite);
    }
}
```

And these are the mappers:

```
public class UserMapper : IUserMapper
{
    private readonly GroupMapper groupMapper;
    private readonly MessageMapper messageMapper;

    public UserMapper(GroupMapper groupMapper, MessageMapper messageMapper)
    {
        this.groupMapper = groupMapper;
        this.messageMapper = messageMapper;
    }

    [ ... ]
}

public class UserMapper : IUserMapper
{   
    public GroupMapper(IUserMapper userMapper, IMessageMapper messageMapper)
    {
        this.userMapper = userMapper;
        this.messageMapper = messageMapper;
    }

    [ ... ]
}

public class MessageMapper : IMessageMapper
{
    private readonly GroupMapper groupMapper;
    private readonly UserMapper userMapper;

    public MessageMapper(GroupMapper groupMapper, UserMapper userMapper)
    {
        this.groupMapper = groupMapper;
        this.userMapper = userMapper;
    }

    [ ... ]
}
```

This is the controller where I'm having problems:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    private IGenericRepository<Data.Models.User> userRepository;
    private IHttpUserFetcher httpUserFetcher;
    private IUserMapper userMapper;

    public UsersController(
        IGenericRepository<Data.Models.User> userRepository,
        IHttpUserFetcher httpUserFetcher,
        IUserMapper userMapper)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.httpUserFetcher = httpUserFetcher;
        this.userMapper = userMapper;
    }

    [ ... ]
}
```

If I remove `IUserMapper userMapper` parameter from `UsersController` constructor, it works.

**Do you know why I'm getting this error?**

**UPDATE:**

I get this exception message:

```
Error activating GroupMapper using implicit self-binding of GroupMapper
A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services.

Activation path:
  5) Injection of dependency GroupMapper into parameter groupMapper of constructor of type UserMapper
  4) Injection of dependency UserMapper into parameter userMapper of constructor of type GroupMapper
  3) Injection of dependency GroupMapper into parameter groupMapper of constructor of type UserMapper
  2) Injection of dependency IUserMapper into parameter userMapper of constructor of type UsersController
  1) Request for UsersController

Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have not declared a dependency for GroupMapper on any implementations of the service.
  2) Consider combining the services into a single one to remove the cycle.
  3) Use property injection instead of constructor injection, and implement IInitializable
     if you need initialization logic to be run after property values have been injected.
```

Comment: Don't you need to tell ninject about ApiControllers? (not used ninject before)

Comment: Have you installed the `Ninject.Web.WebApi` package from nuget?

Answer (score 1):

For WebApi 2, you just need to install [Ninject Web Host for WebApi 2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost/). Then it will create NinjectWebCommon.

[image]

Here is an example -

### NinjectWebCommon

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    ...
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
       ...
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>().InRequestScope();
    }        
}
```

Controller

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UsersController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    // GET: api/Users
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return _userService.GetUsers();
    }
}
```

### Service

```
public interface IUserService
{
    string[] GetUsers();
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public string[] GetUsers()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

**Note:** Create a sample application first before binding all service classes. Otherwise, you won't be able to figure out what service class is forget to bind.

Comment: **FYI:** If you need to map one object to another, you might want to look at [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: @VansFannel As I said, you need to inject one class at a time and test it. If you inject many dependencies at once, it is not easy to debug. Now, the second error is totally different from your original question. **The second error said you have circular dependencies - UserMapper depends on GroupMapper and vice versa, so you need to remove from one.**

Comment: I don't need to debug anything the problem here is a cycle dependency that I don't know how to resolve.

Comment: As I said **you need to remove those circular dependencies** -  ***remove UserMapper from GroupMapper or GroupMapper from UserMapper***. You can only have one; you cannot have both.